# Cleanly Setting up multiple models in FactoryGirl for a test/spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have been picking up on Rails best practices and learning to write good tests for my rails application.

I am using rspec + FactoryGirl to test at the moment.

For a while I was writing basic model and controller specs which usually required to set up only a couple of models and associations.

Now I have a Model with a complex algorithm which does a lot of calculations based on different models.

To test this method, I almost need all the models of my app to exists in test database with all associated relationships built between them.

Now things are getting overwhelming. I need to keep track if all factories are correctly referencing each other. Also I need to verify if all factories have been created properly.
Also a lot of FactoryGirl.create(:model) calls in my before(:each) method.

I have a feeling that I am not doing things right. What is the best way to go about this situation? Most books and examples only cover only the very basic cases.

Any pointers ideas and approches are welcomed.(Hope this question is not too wide in scope)

**Example:**

My application has multiple `projects`. Each project has_many `indexes` , `companies` and `mastertags`. Each company has_many `channels`. Every channel has_many `channel_tag_weights` across different `mastertags`. Also every channel has_many `Rawdatas`.

This could be an example of a minimum model setup required.

Comment: Some example code would help

Comment: Updated with general scenario.

Comment: you can generate helper methods, where you separate your factory girl code, for example def generate_project_with_indexes ... end def generate_project_with_companies .. end, and so on. through this you minimize your code.. but if your app grows, your test code also grows, that´s normal. so you are not doing things false

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a gem for this called [stepford](https://github.com/garysweaver/stepford).

In your gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'stepford'
  #...
end
```

Then `bundle install`.

Back up your factories.rb or existing multiple files containing factories. In fact, you need to move them out of the way because if it loads other factories, that can interfere.

Then: `bundle exec stepford factories --path spec` (if want to put factories.rb in the spec dir- there are other options to create a factory per model, etc. though).

We had problems with dependencies that needed to be created where there were foreign key constraints. In the process, I wrote the [modelist](https://github.com/garysweaver/modelist/) gem that can help identify circular dependencies, which you might want to check out and run if you are working with legacy data. And Stepford's deep creation methods get around these issues. But, we've started to steer away from using the deep_* methods of Stepford, even though we still use it a little. It is just better to be specific about what you are doing and use factory girl directly, even though it can make test code more brittle and overly-complicated looking.

You could also look at fixtures, or [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist). It really just depends on what you need.

If you need to actually create all of the code for the models, that is a different problem. I wrote a script to generate models for the local legacy schema (which was quite large), and it did help, but it took months of iterative work. The thing is that the schema itself is not (necessarily) the definitive description of the associations or setup in the models. To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, I wrote a number of gems to assist with some of the things that legacy apps, etc. were doing/had done that we had to deal with like undeletable, activerecord-define_nils, mark_only, activerecord-custom_timestamps, activerecord-native_db_types_override, and some others in earlier attempts. And we use some great gems that already existed like composite_primary_keys and foreigner.

Some other things we grappled with was using of MTI (multiple table inheritance), which despite a few gems out there that try to help, we ended up handling it ourselves in our models via hooks, etc. And we merged some schemas (not something to take lightly, but the divisions weren't necessary, and apartment, second_base and similar gems would be adding to the complexity, not even considering inability to join, use normal queries).

*Please note: in our case we had a lot of tables. If you don't have quite as many, you still might use Stepford to maybe make the first creation of factories a little easier, but then I think you will be ok.*

Comment: @Myth17 You're using Mongoid? Sorry, you didn't specify that in the original question. :( Assuming it doesn't work because of a few of the things I'm doing, so please open an issue in: https://github.com/garysweaver/stepford/issues and will take a look at it. PR's welcome. (It also needs cleanup, maybe use eager load vs. path dependent model file loading, more tests, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I get into this type of situation, I try to make sure that all of my FactoryGirl models take advantage of FactoryGirl's built in association methods:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

That way the associated models that are required in order for a single model to validate properly are present. FactoryGirl will go through the process of populating your database with the extra test data.

Because you are using has_many associations, you will want to study the after(:create) method of the factory definition in order to set up your associations properly. This will also allow you to create definitions specific to these deeply integrated specs, and keep simpler factories independent for the simpler specs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing only a method, that is unit testing.

I don't think you need to setup too many things.

A method has input and output, you just feed it with examples of inputs created by you manually, and expect it to generate right output.

If a method has too much things to concern, you can split it into several methods, and unit testing each one.

When times for integration testing, the whole environment should be setup. And yes, you need to prepare all the factories needed.